# Sharepoint 2010 : Nintex Workflow does not refresh UserInfo from WSS_Content

Tags: user-profile, user-accounts, nintex

I have an intranet SharePoint 2010 application. The user info is gathered from Active Directory.

One of our new employee's account was created with a wrong surname by our technicians. Then, he renamed the account.

After renaming, SharePoint sites which were already visited by the user could not refresh the `UserInfo` data (this is a whole another problem). I connected the `WSS_Content` Databases and updated the `tp_Login`, `tp_Title` and `tp_Email` fields of `UserInfo` table with the new values.

However, Nintex Workflow still sends the mails to the wrong address.

When I check the account which the tasks are assigned to, I see the correct account name but incorrect title and email addresses.

The user is capable of approving her tasks, but the mails are being sent to the wrong address.

So, my question is, how should I make Nintex refresh its user database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying data directly in the SharePoint [databases is unsupported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-products-and-by-windows-sharepoint-services). The proper way to fix this is to execute a `Move-SPUser`. The full cmdlet would be similar to the following.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|domain\username' -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias 'domain\fixedUsername' -IgnoreSid
```